# No more prerelease test on the buildfarm?

Tags: ros, buildfarm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'd like to make a prerelease test for a package in Indigo **on the buildfarm** as described at
http://wiki.ros.org/action/fullsearch/bloom/Tutorials/PrereleaseTest?dist=indigo#bloom.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-PrereleaseTest.2BAC8-indigo.Prepare_the_release

Thus I go to http://prerelease.ros.org. Then I click on "Old Site" (on the top right) and choose "Indigo". I select my package, enter my email address and click on "Start Testing". But then the new page is loaded where the prerelease command is generated to run the test locally.

How can I run a prerelease test for an Indigo package on the buildfarm? Or can this only be done locally?

Thank you for any hint!

Regards,
Sabrina

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219500/no-more-prerelease-test-on-the-buildfarm?/) by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 285 on 2015-10-20

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you need to run the prereleases locally now. No, there is no build farm available which performs the build for you anymore.

This change was announces in http://lists.ros.org/pipermail/ros-users/2015-May/069430.html

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2015-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) on 2015-10-22**:
Thank you. I will a look at locally performed prerelease tests.